# EF Core 6 adds a default value in SQL when nullable reference types are on and a column is changed from string? to string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, nullable-reference-types, ef-core-6.0

Nullable Reference Types are turned on for my project and I have an entity in my EF Core model which had a `string?` property that I changed to `string.`

old:

```
public string? Name { get; set; };
```

new:

```
public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
```

I then generated a migration and EF added a default value to the column

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "Name",
    table: "MyTable",
    type: "varchar(25)",
    unicode: false,
    maxLength: 25,
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: "", // <-- here
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "varchar(25)",
    oldUnicode: false,
    oldMaxLength: 25,
    oldNullable: true);
```

In SQL

```
DECLARE @var0 sysname;
SELECT @var0 = [d].[name]
FROM [sys].[default_constraints] [d]
INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] [c] ON [d].[parent_column_id] = [c].[column_id] AND [d].[parent_object_id] = [c].[object_id]
WHERE ([d].[parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'[MyTable]') AND [c].[name] = N'Name');
IF @var0 IS NOT NULL EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE [MyTable] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + '];');
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [Name] varchar(25) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD DEFAULT '' FOR [Name];
GO
```

But instead of having the database generate a default value if null is sent, I want an exception to be thrown, so the user must input a value.

I already tried adding

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

or

```
HasDefaultValueSql(null)
```

or

```
HasDefaultValue(null)
```

but that does not change anything.

How can I tell EF Core to not generate a default for that column?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. Your field in your code is not-null. You *cannot* pass null. What user would be passing null how? What exactly do you want to protect against? People running arbitrary SQL on the database?

Comment: Yes, I want to protect against people (developers) running arbitrary SQL, legacy applications and libraries that do not correctly handle nullable reference types (serialization and mapping through reflection).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Entity Framework has some tricks up it's sleeve, but with normal SQL, you would need *two* changes. One change of the NOT NULL status, that *requires* a default value, because what else should that field be set to if a null-value is encountered. And then a second change, that removes the default value from an already NOT NULL field.

So I would not be surprised if Entity Framework needed those two seperate steps, too. Just create two migrations, that should work.

Comment: Entity Framework creates only 1 migration and the one migration does not have the two steps, you mentioned. I'm aware of that pattern, but in fact it is not needed in my case, because the MyTable does not have NULL values in the Name column anyway. Apart from that, EF does not even know what is inside the database when the Migration is generated, that is pure C# code (and also when the SQL out of that code is generated, it has no connection to the real database).